# Google Maps Indoor

Tags: android, maps

Estou criando uma aplicação android, e estou fazendo uso da api do Google Maps, no site do google maps, tem a opção de mapas indoor, e estou tentando utilizá-los na minha aplicação, porem quando tento criar uma rota dentro desses estabelecimentos passando a minha posição atual a uma posição fixa, a trajetoria que o google me retorna é na rua a frente do estabelecimento e mais quando faço o mesmo teste pelo site, ele me retorna a rota correta por dentro do estabelecimento, gostaria de saber se é possível traçar esse percurso pela API v3 do Google Maps ?